# DTE2 _applicationObject reading filename in folder

Tags: add-in, envdte

below is the current codes  i have.
what it does is basically loop thru project solution project file and detect if it is a C# file. however it can't detect files that are put in a folder , how can i modify it to read a C# file in a solution folder.

Regards , Andy

```
  foreach (var projectItem in
            _applicationObject.Solution.Projects.Cast<Project>().SelectMany(project => project.ProjectItems.Cast<ProjectItem>()))
        {
            //for (var i = 0; i < projectItem.FileCount; i++)
            //{


            if (projectItem.FileCount > 0 && projectItem.Name.EndsWith(".cs")) // check if project is .Cs files
            {
                string fileName;
                try
                {

                    fileName = projectItem.FileNames[0];
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                //end of find filename

            }


        }
```

Answer (score 1):

This will print all items in the solution, I believe.
It works with C++ solution in VS 2012.

```
    // XXX  Test
    IEnumerator enumerator = m_applicationObject.Solution.GetEnumerator();
    string indent = "  ";
    while (enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        Project p = enumerator.Current as Project;
        if (p != null)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(p.Name);
            ProcessProjectItems(p.ProjectItems, indent);
        }
    }


// XXX  Test
void ProcessProjectItems(ProjectItems pis, string indent)
{
    if (pis == null)
        return;

    IEnumerator items = pis.GetEnumerator();
    while (items.MoveNext())
    {
        ProjectItem pi = items.Current as ProjectItem;
        if (pi != null)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(indent + pi.Name);

            if (pi.ProjectItems != null)
            {
                ProcessProjectItems(pi.ProjectItems, indent + "  ");
            }
            else
            {
                Project p = pi.Object as Project;
                if (p != null && p.ProjectItems != null)
                    ProcessProjectItems(p.ProjectItems, indent + "  ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```